# Frequent queries on android contacts returns null

Tags: android, contactscontract

I'm using the following code segment to get phone numbers of a contact by contact ID

```
private static ArrayList<PhoneName> getPhonesFromID(Context context,
            String contactID, String column) {
        // Run query
        Uri uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;
        String[] projection = new String[] {
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.STARRED,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE };
        String selection = column + " = '" + contactID + "'";
        String[] selectionArgs = null;
        String sortOrder = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER
                + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection,
                selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);

        if (cursor == null)
            return null;

        int numberIndex = cursor
                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
        int nameIndex = cursor
                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);
        int typeIndex = cursor
                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE);
        int favIndex = cursor
                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.STARRED);

        ArrayList<PhoneName> phones = new ArrayList<PhoneName>();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            PhoneName pn = new PhoneName();
            pn.name = cursor.getString(nameIndex);
            pn.number = cursor.getString(numberIndex);
            pn.starred = cursor.getString(favIndex);
            pn.state = DataHelper.getInstance(context)
                    .getSubscriptionStateByNumber(pn.number);
            Log.d("Number", pn.number);
            int type = cursor.getInt(typeIndex);
            if (type == ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME) {
                pn.type = "Home";
            } else if (type == ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE) {
                pn.type = "Mobile";
            } else if (type == ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK) {
                pn.type = "work";
            } else {
                pn.type = "other";
            }
            phones.add(pn);
        }

        cursor.close();
        return phones;
    }
```

Here's PhoneName is my self-defined class to store contact information of that specific contact. This function is called like:

```
getPhonesFromID(context, _id,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID);
```

I'm getting the contact information correctly but here's the problem, sometimes this function returns null when I make frequent queries. When this problem occurs, default people application of my android don't show any contact too. All contacts are like vanished. Then if I close my application and restart then it shows all contacts like before. Then again when I go to the contact details of a contact from my application it works fine several times and then all contacts are gone again.
This is a weird problem and I don't know actually what is happening here. I double checked my queries and couldn't figure out what's wrong in here.

Comment: where do you use this method? can you post the usage?

Comment: I'm making an application like phonebook. It populates all contacts first and then by clicking on each contacts it goes to another fragment showing the details of that specific contact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, this problem got solved.

Like I said, my application is like Phonebook and I had to show a favourite icon for each contact in the list which is my favourite contact. In my case, I had a function like `isFavourite()` to determine if a contact is in my favourite list or not and this is called in every single time when a contact row is loading.

Each time I open a cursor to get the query result and it was found that the cursor was not closed anywhere. So basically, closing the cursor properly solved the problem! Cheers!